# "not a valid identifier" when I do "export $PATH"

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

When I run `export $PATH` in bash, I get the error `not a valid identifier`. Why?

Comment: In bash and other shells, `$` is “value of”. You're exporting the variable `PATH`, not accessing its value, so it's `export PATH` with no `$`.

Comment: A more common similar issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/529919/how-to-fix-not-a-valid-identifier-error-after-setting-environment-variables

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Running `export $PATH` will try to export a variable with a name equal to the **value** of `$PATH` (after [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and filename generation). That is, it's equivalent to writing something like `export /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. And since `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` is not a valid variable name, it fails. **What you want to do is `export PATH`.**

[`export`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Variable_Types) (equivalent to `declare -x` when not called within a function) in Bash maps the shell variable to an environment variable, so it is passed to commands executed from now one (in child processes or otherwise).

To print the value of a variable safely and readably, use `printf '%q\n' "$PATH"` or `typeset -p PATH` to print its definition.

Comment: Basically I have created some variables, JAVA_HOME, MAVEN_HOME and want to make sure that bash has properly set them, so I export $PATH to see if the path variables have been properly set to the PATH variable

Comment: This is shell dependent, not OS dependent. I would be surprised if `export` ever worked like that in Bash.

Comment: Additionally, the PATH variable is already exported and does not need to be exported again.

Answer (score 28):

The following command `export $PATH=somePath` will return `not a valid identifier` and that is because of the `$` before the `PATH` variable.

solution:

`export PATH=somePath`

Answer (score 7):

You should use it this way:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/something/bin
```

Instead of:

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/something/bin
```

just remove the `$` sign from the left hand side.

Answer (score -1):

You probably had a need to append a $PATH to your existing PATH variable ?

```
export PATH=$PATH:/something/bin
```

Comment: OK, this is in the same ball park as the question, but it’s out in left field.