# bash : export: `PATH:home/pi/netkit/bin:/usr/local ... invalid indentifier

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

Currently I'm struggling with some notification every time I open terminal:

```
bash: export: `PATH:home/pi/netkit/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:bin:/usr/local/games/:/usr/games' : not a valid identifier
```

Everything seems to be working fine. But how to get rid of this annoying notification?

Comment: It should start with `PATH=`; not `PATH:`.

Comment: And a typo : `.... /usr/local/games/:/usr/games` → Must be ` .... /usr/local/games:/usr/games` -

Comment: Or that :bin: in there got relocated

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79658/not-a-valid-identifier-when-i-do-export-path is not a duplicate question: This other says “when I do `export $PATH …`” this one says “when I open a terminal”. Same answer ≠ same question. What is more the answer is not even the same. This user needs to find the offending bit of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/whatever/you/want
```

This will do what you meant :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to find the code that is in error. This may help

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'PATH:home/pi/netkit/bin:/'

find /etc -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'PATH:home/pi/netkit/bin:/'
```

Comment: @JanWieczorek If you accept an answer, then it is custom to tick ✓ the answer that you accept.