# After starting terminal always getting bash: export: "path" not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, environment-variables, path

I was trying to install Angularjs through the Ubuntu terminal and to have proper install, I'd to change the path. Maybe during these time I've messed up with the path. After this, when I'm starting Ubuntu terminal, I'm always getting these three message at top of the terminal window:

```
bash: export: `/usr/bin/java': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/usr/share/java': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz': not a valid identifier
```

I've tried to find the solution in few forums excluding this, but couldn't solve it. I've followed this [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79658/not-a-valid-identifier-when-i-do-export-path) but it couldn't change anything.

My Java is working properly, I can open this command with a warning `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`

What should I do to fix the problem?

Edition: After running
I'm getting this command `grep export ~/.bashrc`, output:

```
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
export JAVA_HOME= /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Please add the (formatted) output of `grep export ~/.bashrc` to your question.

Comment: Also, _never_ run `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`! You own your bashrc there is no reason to ever edit it as root. What warning are you getting?

Comment: The lines should look like `export VAR=value` - make sure there are no blanks around the `=`

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79658/not-a-valid-identifier-when-i-do-export-path or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042369/bash-export-not-a-valid-identifier

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick answer. I'm sorry late reply. 

@roaima, I've edited the question and put output 'grep export ~/.bashrc'.

Comment: @terdon,  thanks for your advice. I've done so as I was following an answer from different forum.

Comment: @Plotnick, sorry I didn't understand what you have meant here. You mean the path of Java in my machine or the path of out the error output I'm getting in terminal window?

Comment: I meant in the .bashrc file, but it looks like you already got an answer. You probably don't need to set JAVA_HOME at all if you just have the system default java installed. If you have multiple versions installed , then JAVA_HOME should be the name of a single directory that contains  the directories and files that comprise one version of java. Under JAVA_HOME there will be a `bin` directory that contains the java compiler.

Comment: @ Mark, you're right, I've got system default Java installed and there is only one version of Java.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `export` line wrongly contains a space after the assignment operator (`=`).

It also contains three values where, to my knowledge, `JAVA_HOME` only accepts one value: the location of the Java HOME directory.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/share/java"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Here is how look Java path in my machine. 

`export JAVA_HOME= /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Sorry, that path was from `.bshrc file`.

Comment: Surprisingly, in `bashrc' file after commenting this line `#export `JAVA_HOME= "/usr/bin/java /usr/share/java` `/usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz"` and left alone this line `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH `, in terminal window the _bash: export: “path” not a valid identifier_ no longer is being showed.

Does it mean that the problem is solved? Or is it like I've made another mess up?

Comment: @Mamun : In addition to what roaima said, you also have spaces *in between* the directory names! I strongly suggest that you try first your  `export` statements on the commandline, before putting them into your *.bashrc*.

Comment: @Mamum commenting out the invalid line would also work, but then you're not setting any value for `JAVA_HOME`. Without that your Java-based programs won't work. And since it's now not set you should comment the second line too, which references it.

Comment: @roaima, surprisingly after commenting the invalid, my Java-based programs work.